# get value from web page using Html Agility Pack

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I am trying to get the value of the "Pool Hashrate" using the [HTML Agility Pack](https://www.nuget.org/packages/HtmlAgilityPack/). Right when I hit my string hash, I get `Object reference not set to an instance of an object`. Can somebody tell me what I am doing wrong?

```
string url = http://p2pool.org/ltcstats.php?address

protected void Page_Load(string address)
{
    string url = address;
    HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
    HtmlDocument doc = web.Load(Url);

    string hash = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("/html/body/div/center/div/table/tbody/tr[1]")[0].InnerText;
}
```

Comment: I believe Html Agility Pack is 1 based.  I would break it down and leave off the InnerText, then do a foreach on your nodes and debug to see if you got any nodes and what is in them.

Comment: I had a similar problem, check this out(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30805833/inspect-element-from-my-wpf-webbrowser-using-inspect-elementsie-chrome-fir)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're trying to access that url, of course it should fail.  That url doesn't return a full document, but just a fragment of html.  There is no `html` tag, there is no `body` tag, just the `div`.  Your xpath query returns nothing and thus the null reference exception.  You need to query the right thing.

When I access that url, it returns this:

```
<div>
    <center>
        <div style="margin-right: 20px;">
        <h3>Personal LTC Stats</h3>
        <table class='zebra-striped'>
        <tr><td>Pool Hashrate: </td><td>66.896 Mh/s</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Your Hashrate: </td><td>0 Mh/s</td></tr>  
        <tr><td>Estimated Payout: </td><td> LTC</td></tr>
        </table>
        </div>
    </center>
</div>
```

Given this, if you wanted to get the `Pool Hashrate`, you'd use a query more like this:

```
/div/center/div/table/tr[1]/td[2]
```

In the end you need to do this:

```
var url = "http://p2pool.org/ltcstats.php?address";
var web = new HtmlWeb();
var doc = web.Load(url);
var xpath = "/div/center/div/table/tr[1]/td[2]";
var poolHashrate = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode(xpath);
if (poolHashrate != null)
{
    var hash = poolHashrate.InnerText;
    // do stuff with hash
}
```

Comment: I see the html and body tags when I look at it

Comment: Well yeah, if you open it through a browser, the browser will add those.  Try again by accessing the site directly.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that xpath is not finding the specified node. You can specify an id to the table or the tr in order to have a smaller xpath

Also, based on your code I assume that you're looking for a single node only, so you may want to use something like this

doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("xpath");

Another good option is using [Fizzler](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Fizzler/)